Are there Kripke-Joyal semantics for terms which involve arrows of the topos (rather than purely variables and connectives)?
I follow Mac Lane and Moerdijk's (slightly informal) presentation of the Mitchell-Benabou language. There, they outline several recursive rules to describe what the terms of the language are and introduce a "forcing" relation:

$U\Vdash\phi(x)[\alpha]$ iff. $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha)\subseteq\{x:\phi(x)\}$ as subobjects of $X$, where $\phi$ is a formula in one free variable $x$ of type $X$ and $\alpha:U\to X$ is any generalised element.

This generalises easily for formulae with plural or no variables. Several theorems ("the Kripke-Joyal semantics") can be proven which help you actually decide whether or not $U\Vdash\phi(x)[\alpha]$ holds by breaking $\phi$ into several connectives and primitive variables. However, there is a notable absence.
According to these authors, if $\sigma$ is a term of the language of type $Y$ and $f:Y\to Z$ is any arrow in the topos, we are permitted a term $f\circ\sigma$ with the obvious interpretation. It is really unclear to me if we can say anything about how to decide, for an arrow $f:Y\to\Omega$, the truth of something like $U\Vdash(f\circ\sigma)(x)[\alpha]$. One would have to work with the subobject classified by $f$, which could be anything. Or even more specifically, if $\phi$ is a formula and $f$ is a "modal operator" i.e. an arrow $\Omega\to\Omega$ it would be interesting to have some formal techniques to help one resolve $U\Vdash(f\circ\phi(x))[\alpha]$.
I think this question is hopelessly general, but I'd be very surprised if some special cases weren't already studied (but I don't even know what a special case would look like). Otherwise I can't help but feel the "Kripke-Joyal semantics" is an incomplete list, and there are going to be very many terms of the internal language whose forcing relations cannot be concretely stated in the external language, in the topos itself. The authors claim these semantics can achieve more or less anything; I'm not so sure, but I'd love to be wrong!

Hmm, I'm curious why they would introduce special terms for that situation, rather than just saying a morphism $f : Y \to Z$ corresponds to a global section of $Z^Y$, and therefore it induces a morphism $U \to 1 \to Z^Y$ for each test object $U$ (which easily can be seen to correspond to the composition of the projection $U \times Y \to Y$ and $f$).

@DanielSchepler I’m not sure what your propose alternative notation is then, to replace $f\circ\sigma$

It would just become a special case of the notation $\varphi(\sigma)$ where $\varphi : Z^Y$ and $\sigma : Y$.

@DanielSchepler I would disagree. You need some way to make the arrow $1\to Z^Y$ a term $\phi$ of the language. This is exactly what this stipulation does; it says these arrows are terms, or more precisely you could construe $\phi$ as the term $\phi\circ u$ where $u:1$ is a variable and $\phi:1\to Z^Y$ is the arrow. Without this stipulation, their presentation offers no way I can see to shoehorn arbitrary arrows into the language

I was suggesting making the arrow into a term of the language, simply via making it into one of the free variables of a formula.

I'm not sure I buy that. A free variable of type $Z^Y$ should be different from a specific arrow $Y\to Z$, to distinguish between "linguistic objects" ~ virtual arrows and actual arrows

OK, maybe that's it.

I'm also more used to this definition that seems simpler and clearer to me: if $\phi$ is a term with free variable $x$ and $x : X \vdash \phi : \Omega$, then the interpretation of the term $\phi$ gives a morphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, X) \to \operatorname{Hom}({-}, \Omega)$; and $U \Vdash \phi[x/\alpha]$ if and only if applying that morphism to $\alpha$ gives $\mathsf{true} \circ ()_U$ where $()_U : U \to 1$.

As far as I know, there is no Kripke-Joyal semantics for such terms, and you would just need to fall back to the general definition.  (An equivalent version of the definition, which will probably be easier to work with in practice: if $\phi$ is a term with free variable $x$ such that $x : X \vdash \phi : \Omega$, then the interpretation of $\phi$ gives a morphism of functors $\operatorname{Hom}({-}, X) \to \operatorname{Hom}({-}, \Omega)$.  Then $U \Vdash \phi[x/\alpha]$ if and only if applying the interpretation of $\phi$ to $\alpha$ gives a morphism equal to $\mathsf{true} \circ ()_U$ where $()_U : U \to 1$.)
That said, in particular cases, you could easily create your own rules in the spirit of Kripke-Joyal semantics for such morphisms of interest, as the existing Kripke-Joyal semantics do for the propositional connectives, ${=}_X : X \times X \to \Omega$, and ${\in}_X : X \times P(X) \to \Omega$.  For example, let us suppose we are working in the topos of presheaves on a topological space, and examining the associated Lawvere-Tierney topology $j : \Omega \to \Omega$.  In this situation, it is probably common to use Kripke-Joyal semantics restricted to the generating set of objects $\{ h_U \mid U ~\textrm{open} \}$, and furthermore it seems natural to allow a slight abuse of notation in writing $U \Vdash \phi[x/\alpha]$ in place of $h_U \Vdash \phi[x/\alpha]$.  Then it is almost trivial to see the following Kripke-Joyal style rule: $U \Vdash j \circ \phi[x/\alpha]$ if and only if there exists an open cover $\{ V_i \mid i : I \}$ of $U$ such that for each $i : I$, $V_i \Vdash \phi[x / (\alpha |_{V_i})]$.  (And of course this generalizes fairly easily to the similar situation of presheaves on a Grothendieck site.)
